Best practices in the formation of the cypress structure
Are there practices that help to group data correctly and effectively?
I am very concerned about the question of how best to store records according to some common feature: there are rows where there are fields id, owner_id, and more...
Question: is it worth storing everything in 1 table (//home/stats_table) or is it better to split it into many small tables based on owner_id (//home/{{owner_id}}/stats_table)

Splitting a table is a good approach if you have reading queries that read this data independently.
If data have the very same structure (but for example different owners) and the usage pattern is loading data per owner - then split tables per owner is a good approach, if not - then better to store them in one huge table.
Be aware that you also can utilize the sort-property of a table, so by adding sort by your owner_id may improve read performance by a lot.
Also I may suggest you to group data based on logical time in it, for example by days, if you are storing time-series data.
